# Android theme without the edge

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

I'm using the Eclipse GUI for android. I want to use the full screen and I'm searching for the attribute, that disables the edge in a theme. I'm using the NoTitleBar theme and a relative layout and I can't place buttons on the edgde of the screen. There are like 10pixels I can't reach. Something like **item name="android:windowNoEdge" true /item**. In addition I can't really make the views/buttons as big as i want, when I try to drag them too a different/bigger shape/size they just shrink back too the original shape/size.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Put this in your **onCreate** method

```
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

before **setContentView()**

**Method 2:**
This will make **entire application** to full-screen, instead of just one Activity.

```
<application 
    ... 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    ... >
```